# Constexpr value as nontype template parameter of pointer type

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, constexpr

The following [code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8d8f4c80bc4555de)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>

using namespace std;


constexpr initializer_list<int> list = {1, 2, 3};

template<const int* begin, const int* end>
bool contains(int v)
{
    if constexpr(begin != end)
    {
        if (*begin = v)
            return true;
        else
            return contains<next(begin), end>(v);
    }
    return false;
}


int main()
{
    cout << contains<list.begin(), list.end()>(2);
    return 0;
}
```

produces some really weird error message:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:25:49: error: no matching function for call to 'contains<list.std::initializer_list<int>::begin(), list.std::initializer_list<int>::end()>(int)'
     cout << contains<list.begin(), list.end()>(2);
                                                 ^
main.cpp:10:6: note: candidate: 'template<const int* begin, const int* end> bool contains(int)'
 bool contains(int v)
      ^~~~~~~~
main.cpp:10:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:25:49: error: the address of '._86' is not a valid template argument
     cout << contains<list.begin(), list.end()>(2);
                                                 ^
main.cpp:25:49: error: 'list.std::initializer_list<int>::end()' is not a valid template argument for 'const int*' because it is not the address of a variable
```

I believe this *could* compile because the compiler has all the information at compile time: `list` is constexpr and so are its `begin`, `end` and `next`. So what prohibits this from working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The initializer list object holds a pointer to an array of 3 `int`s which actually have the values 1, 2, 3. When you call `.begin()`, a pointer to the first element (with value 1) is returned. However, you are not allowed to use a pointer to an array element as a template argument, since the standard specifies that a template parameter of pointer type shall not point to "a subobject" ([temp.arg.nontype]/2.1). I'm not sure why this restriction exists, though.

Comment: The restriction exists because implementing it would require changing the name mangling to support serializing subobject identifiers into the name, which, simply put, would not be fun.